# xml to new format xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have a xml file, look like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
  <Game GameID="535f61f62cfd9a50160011af_nl" Game_Title="Hermitage_Vincent" NumberOfConversants="2" SyncType="Automatic" LifeSpan="P2Y">
    <DynamicStructure>
      <Connection ConnectionID="106358" From_PhraseID="tg0if2-jc8-k6i-spg-2tof46ftr_nl" To_PhraseID="jmrgi1-dst-kt6-roo-lrahuk6tj_nl" PresentedText_PhraseID="jmrgi1-dst-kt6-roo-lrahuk6tj_nl" From_ActionID="" To_ActionID="" SpecificSituationID="" SettingOptionValue="" SettingOptionID=""/>
      <Connection ConnectionID="106359" From_PhraseID="1" To_PhraseID="tg1c8p-jgg-dbh-b4l-hir5cpla7_nl" PresentedText_PhraseID="tg1c8p-jgg-dbh-b4l-hir5cpla7_nl" From_ActionID="" To_ActionID="" SpecificSituationID="" SettingOptionValue="" SettingOptionID=""/>
      -miah9qqh6_nl" PresentedText_PhraseID="ebgtcu-sn1-cls-87k-miah9qqh6_nl" From_ActionID="" To_ActionID="" SpecificSituationID="" SettingOptionValue="" SettingOptionID=""/>
    </DynamicStructure>
  </Game>
  <Phrase PhraseID="3uos6o-bi2-619-4rf-b6bro6qrj_nl" Language="nl">
    <Media MediaID="3uos6o-bi2-619-4rf-b6bro6qrj_nl">
      <Text TextID="3uos6o-bi2-619-4rf-b6bro6qrj_nl" String="Why did you paint with little dots?" LipSync_AnimationID=""/>
    </Media>
  </Phrase>
</Content>
 </Assets>
</ChatMapperProject>
```

I want to transform it to another format look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ChatMapperProject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Title="Example.cmp" Version="1.1.0.0" Author="Ben" EmphasisColor1="#E7955B" EmphasisColor1Label="Addresses" EmphasisColor2="#44B634" EmphasisColor2Label="" EmphasisColor3="#4688E6" EmphasisColor3Label="" EmphasisColor4="#CCCCCC" EmphasisColor4Label="Action">
    <Conversations>
      <Conversation ID="1" NodeColor="Red">
        <Fields>
          <Field Type="Text" Hint="The title of this conversation.">
            <Title>Title</Title>
            <Value>Karen's House</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Type="Files" Hint="A collection of image files that represent this conversation. The first is used as the background image.">
            <Title>Pictures</Title>
            <Value>[]</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Type="Text" Hint="A short description of what happens in this conversation.">
            <Title>Description</Title>
            <Value>The demonstrations start at Karen's house where she finds out what happened to her little sister. The main goal of this conversation to learn the address of Tommy's work.</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Type="Actor" Hint="The actor who is doing most of the talking, or initiates this conversation.">
            <Title>Actor</Title>
            <Value>1</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Type="Actor" Hint="The actor who is approached or is mostly talked to.">
            <Title>Conversant</Title>
            <Value>2</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Type="Text" Hint="The scene that this conversation is used in.">
            <Title>Scene</Title>
            <Value>1A</Value>
          </Field>
        </Fields>
        <DialogEntries>
          <DialogEntry ID="0" ConversationID="1" IsRoot="true" IsGroup="false" NodeColor="White" DelaySimStatus="false" FalseCondtionAction="Block" ConditionPriority="Normal">
            <Fields>
              <Field Type="Text" Hint="The title of this dialogue.">
                <Title>Title</Title>
                <Value>START</Value>
              </Field>
              <Field Type="Files" Hint="A collection of image files that represent this dialogue.">
                <Title>Pictures</Title>
                <Value>[]</Value>
              </Field>
              <Field Type="Text" Hint="A short description of what happens in this dialogue.">
                <Title>Description</Title>
                <Value />
              </Field>
              <Field Type="Actor" Hint="The actor who is talking.">
                <Title>Actor</Title>
                <Value>1</Value>
              </Field>
              <Field Type="Actor" Hint="The actor who is listening.">
                <Title>Conversant</Title>
                <Value>2</Value>
              </Field>
            </Fields>
            <OutgoingLinks>
              <Link ConversationID="1" OriginDialogID="0" DestinationDialogID="1" IsConnector="false" />
            </OutgoingLinks>
            <ConditionsString>Dialog[3].SimStatus ~= "WasDisplayed"</ConditionsString>
            <UserScript />
          </DialogEntry>
      </DialogEntries>
     </Conversation>
    </Conversations>
   </Assets>
</ChatMapperProject>
```

xml...I am writing it with c# in unity...But it doesn't work...Anyone got an example? Thanks in advance... 
[that is my test project in unity](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l0eut04rh4x46n7/AACqfWpjbFBxYuEWDQRTqsUHa?dl=0)

Comment: (a) I can't see any connection between the input and the output. (b) I can't tell you what's wrong with your code without seeing your code (no, I'm not going to install it from dropbox). (c) C# is the wrong tool for this job. Use XSLT - it will be about a tenth the number of lines of code.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800978/xml-to-new-xml-using-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

If you're just trying to make the XML look pretty and formatted, then you can try this:

```
try
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    return doc.ToString();
}
catch
{
    return xml;
}
```

Comment: Clearly, the OP wants to do more than pretty up the XML.